# What is the meaning of Jack Burton's words to Margo in truck?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, big-trouble-in-little-china

In ***Big Trouble in Little China***, Jack Burton says these words to Margo in the truck during the final scenes:

> Margo: What was that?
>
> Jack Burton: 6.9 on the Richter scale.

There is no Richter Scale in the truck. Then what is the meaning of Jack Burton's words to Margo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was the roar and vibration of his uber-macho truck starting up that startled Margo.  He was metaphorically comparing its power to that of an massive earthquake.

Answer (score 2):

It's been too long since I've seen the movie, so I'm struggling to remember context of that quote... but the [Richter scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richter_magnitude_scale) is used to measure the magnitude of an earthquake.  It's a logarithmic scale.

As someone who spent 14 years in southern California, I can assure you that a 6.9 would be a massive earthquake.  (For reference, the [1989 earthquake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1989_Loma_Prieta_earthquake) that disrupted the 1989 World Series was a 6.9, and cost an estimated $6 billion in property damage.)

Jack is obviously making a reference to something big, powerful, and dangerous.

Answer (score -2):

It's the end of the film, and one is asking the other what has just happened to them. What happened is being compared to an earthquake on a large scale.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).